# JQuery Maths - not 100% sure how to manage what i need

Tags: jquery

wonder if someone can help me i know what i want to achive but struggling to get it to work.

```
if (left_indent == ((imageReelWidth * 2) - ((imageReelWidth * 2) - imageWidth)) {
 alert ("boo");      
}
```

i know the above is not right, what i need is:

i have two varables:
imageReelWidth which has a value of lets say 800
imageWidth which has a value of lets say 200

i need an alert to trigger when a varable called left_indent gets to -600

hope that explains it a little better

that is negative 600

---

Sorry sorted it, it was just my bad maths

> if (left_indent == (imageReelWidth - (imageReelWidth*2-imageWidth))) {
>   alert ("boo"); }

Comment: `((imageReelWidth * 2) - ((imageReelWidth * 2) - imageWidth)` will equals `-200`, so it won't reach your `alert`.

Comment: You're also struggling to communicate what it is you want to achieve. What's the question here? You need to include a lot more details, such as where these numbers come from, what they represent, when this code is supposed to be run, etc.

Comment: sorry explained a little better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want...

```
if (left_indent == (imageWidth - imageReelWidth)) {
    alert ("boo");      
}
```